# SAS Format Data from "flat" data source

Tags: sas

Hope you can help.

Im trying to read flat data from mainframe with my program in SAS with this code:

```
INFILE DG121 TRUNCOVER
Missover FIRSTOBS=2 ;


INPUT
@ 1 LAENGDE IB2.
@ 3 TOTANM IB2.
@ 5 REXHTYP IB2.
@ 7 RMODTAFD PD3.
@ 10 RANVDATO PD5.
@ 15 RKUNDENR PD6. 
@ 21 RBRKODE PD2.
@ 23 RRAADGIV ÅCHAR1.
@ 24 RKUNDKAT ÅCHAR3.
@ 27 RMAXOPR PD8.2
@ 35 RLOBTIDO PD2.
@ 37 RPRODBET ÅCHAR6.
@ 43 RMEDIE ÅCHAR5.
@ 48 ROPSIG ZD3.
@ 69 BRUGER IB4.

I get the Note in my log:
NOTE: Invalid data for RMODTAFD in line 47291 7-9.
NOTE: Invalid data for RANVDATO in line 47291 10-14.
NOTE: Invalid data for RKUNDENR in line 47291 15-20.
NOTE: Invalid data for RBRKODE in line 47291 21-22.
NOTE: Invalid data for RMAXOPR in line 47291 27-34.
NOTE: Invalid data for RLOBTIDO in line 47291 35-36.
NOTE: Invalid data for ROPSIG in line 47291 48-50.
ERROR: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached.  Further errors of this type will not be printed.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                      

47291     .ü.......................................................^.......................5\.................
    ZONE  0A00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0500FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0FEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    NUMR  0100FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0F0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF550FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

     101  .......................rrrr{.r{.rr{...........¸...èhÇ..{..}.{ 161
    ZONE  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0999990990999FFF00001120900058632900429
    NUMR  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF99999C99C999CFFF00691462D00548862C0078C
LAENGDE=161 TOTANM=0 REXHTYP=-1 RMODTAFD=. RANVDATO=. RKUNDENR=. RBRKODE=. RRAADGIV=¤ RKUNDKAT=¤¤¤ RMAXOPR=. RLOBTIDO=.
RPRODBET=¤¤¤¤¤¤ RMEDIE=¤¤¤¤¤ ROPSIG=. BRUGER=-1 _ERROR_=1 _N_=47290
NOTE: EOV macro was not able to obtain an additional extent for library data set SYS15133.T093707.RA000.G46973.R0566335, volume 
      number 1. System rc = 00000B37; Reason code = 00000004.
ERROR: Write to WORK.WAB.DATA failed. File is full and may be damaged.
```

**My question is.
I know my PD format cannot read char. But can i in some way make sas skip the data it cannot read so i dont get the note:
NOTE: Invalid data for ROPSIG in line 47291 48-50**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **??** input format modifier to get rid of error and make sas move on with the processing.  Check out Format modifier in the SAS documentation for INPUT statement ->[Format Modifiers for Error Reporting](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146292.htm).

```
data input_data;
infile datalines missover;
input age ?? 8.;
datalines;
12
45
32
A
54
Z
66
;;;;
run;
proc print data=input_data;run;
```

So your code should be like :

```
INPUT
@ 1 LAENGDE ?? IB2.
@ 3 TOTANM  ?? IB2.
@ 5 REXHTYP ?? IB2.
@ 7 RMODTAFD ?? PD3.
.
.
.
```

Also, i wanted to point out that based on your log, the error that is showing up is for space out( B37 is out of space error on Mainframe). Try increasing the allocation size of the library where the dataset is getting created to prevent that error.

Comment: Thank you sushill. It was just what i was looking for!

Regarding the out of space error. Can i increase the workspace in my SAS or do i somehow need to do it on the mainframe?

Comment: SAS would be using a mainframe location as WORK path. Check out the DDNAME WORK on the expanded log and you will be able to see the mainframe dataset. Either it would a permanent data or a temporary dataset, regardless you would need to increase the SPACE= parameter value to avoid B37 error.

Comment: I can see my mainframe dataset is:
NOTE: The infile DG121 is:
      Dsname=G41066.PUREX.HK000.WAB.HTB.DG121,
      Unit=3390,Volume=A0243C,Disp=SHR,Blksize=27998,
      Lrecl=23472,Recfm=VB

But can i just write in my program, SPACE= X numbers i want in my dataset?

Comment: no.i think you got confused with the term dataset. Check out your mainframe job in sar/ispf and check out the 3rd bucket LOG( this contains the expanded JCL job). within this try finding the SAS step and within that WORK DDNAME. That should show you the mainframe location which forms your WORK library. Increase that library allocation by overriding the path. Refer a mainframe specialist at your site to help you understand the allocation etc.